# Node.js - Website Scraper With Loop

Tags: node.js, loops, asynchronous, web-scraping

I would like to scrape data from a website.

Everything went great until I did not want to use the loop to massively scrape the data from many subpages.

I would like it to work like this:

```
var scrape = require('website-scraper');


for(i = 1; i < 150; i++){
  scrape({
        urls: ['https://example.com?id='+i],
        urlFilter: function(url){
          return url.startsWith('https://example.com');
        },
        recursive: true,
        maxRecursiveDepth: 10,
        filenameGenerator: 'bySiteStructure',
        directory: 'page/'+i,
  }).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
}
```

But then the loop does not wait until the scrape is ready.

I would like the loop to wait for a scrape and only then start working with the next page.

Could someone do this for me, and I will transfer it to my code?
Or at least explain how to proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `scrape` is asynchronous, which is pretty much the whole idea of Node.js. You’ll probably want to do some research using that keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrape` is asynchronous. for loop won't wait for it.

You might want to pass a callback function to then.

```
  scrape({
        urls: ['https://example.com?id='+i],
        urlFilter: function(url){
          return url.startsWith('https://example.com');
        },
        recursive: true,
        maxRecursiveDepth: 10,
        filenameGenerator: 'bySiteStructure',
        directory: 'page/'+i,
  }).then(function(result) {
     // 'result' will be an array of Resources object.
     // your code here to process the result.
  }).catch(console.log);
```